# How start the FragmentActivity by displaying the middle fragment's view first

Tags: android

I just started learning android.Hope this isn't silly question.Here it is

My `FragmentAdapter` has a `List` of `Fragment`s,Say 3 Fragments 1,2,3.

I have set this `FragmentAdapter` for my `ViewPager` using `myViewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentAdapter);`

So this application kicks off by displaying **view of Fragment 1**.How do I start the Application by displaying `Fragment` 2's `View` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setCurrentItem(index)` to switch your current page.

In this case, you would want to do:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ... init code ...
    myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
```

See the [ViewPager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29) for more information. You may wish to use the variation of this method which allows you specify where there should be a smooth scroll, and set it as `false`, otherwise the user may see the animation the moment the app opens and it could be confusing. For example,

```
myViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
```

Comment: so myViewPager.setAdapter() always sets the 0th View as Default Start view? we are only setting 1st view in OnCreate() only after 0th view was displayed first right?

Comment: That is correct, and that is also why you would want to disable the scrolling animation when you manually change the view.